# Applying the activation link to linked text in the notification email

Tags: templating, emails, activation

Whether I use an HTML email template or not, there are a few problems with the activation email link that appears as follows:

http://localhost.dev/actions/users/verifyemail?code=lzxmSVbLE~scHE5KPuL7Rk2oZqJbafyD&id=c3b6d053-2d69-43a8-9b1a-3210df88993c

1. Links output as URLs in emails unfortunately tend to trigger spam filters. It's best practice to ensure that you're always wrapping links around real text, not the same URL, linked.
2. More importantly, that link consistently breaks on the `/verifyemail...` portion (I'm viewing it in the Fastmail web client) and is not clickable. This occurs with the basic notification formatting, and within my HTML email template.

I tried wrapping the link in HTML markup under Email Settings -> Messages, and included `autoescape false` in my HTML email template (around `{{body}}`), but I get escaped HTML in the email. (I'm assuming that's because you're using the same message text for multipart HTML & text emails.)

My question is: Is there any way available presently to apply the activation link to linked text rather than outputting it directly in the email?

(This is a subscription site allowing users to self-register, so a non-clickable link in an email is one more hurdle I'd like to avoid.)

Thanks!

Comment: Mark, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Hi, John! I've heard nothing on this front. I have not looked at the 2.5 beta yet either to see if there are any changes there.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this has been fixed since this old question, but just wrapping `{{link}}` variable in `<a>` tag lets me send custom HTML notifications with working clickable text links.

Screenshot of messages settings:

[image: Messages settings]

Screenshot of custom HTML email received:

[image: Custom HTML email received]

Perhaps this won't work for the text version of the email, but if needed I suggest you to use this excellent plugin which let you send custom notifications in both HTML and text versions: [Sprout Emails](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email).